# Is it possible to use starts_with/ends_with from C++20 to compare case insensitive?

Tags: c++, string, c++20

With C++20 and [P0457](https://wg21.link/P0457) we get member functions for `string` and `string_view` that checks prefixes and suffixes:

`starts_with()`, `ends_with()`

Is there a way to compare strings case-insensitively?

For example this check returns `false`:

```cpp
const std::string url { "https://isocpp.org" };
    
if (url.starts_with("HTTPS"))
    std::cout << "you're using the correct site!\n";
```

For example in boost we have [`istarts_with`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/istarts_with.html) that does such a comparison.

One way is to "normalise" the string and the prefix/suffix you want to check (make it all lowercase for example), but this requires extra copies of the objects.

Comment: `std::islower`and `std::isupper`?? This does not required C++20.

Comment: @MyClass how should those two function help to do a case insensitive checks if a string start or ends with a char sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`starts_with` and `ends_with` use the `char_traits` of the string. You can extend the default `char_traits` to uses case-insensitive comparison:

```
struct case_insensitive_traits : public std::char_traits<char> {
    static bool eq(char c1, char c2) {
         return std::toupper(c1) == std::toupper(c2);
     }
    static bool lt(char c1, char c2) {
         return std::toupper(c1) <  std::toupper(c2);
    }
    static int compare(const char* s1, const char* s2, std::size_t n) {
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (lt(*s1, *s2)) return -1;
            if (lt(*s2, *s1)) return 1;
            ++s1; ++s2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
```

This allows you to construct a string type on which all comparisons are case-insensitive:

```
using case_insensitive_string =
    std::basic_string<char, case_insensitive_traits>;

case_insensitive_string cistr = "Fundamental";

cistr.starts_with("fun"); // true
cistr == "FUNDAMENTAL"; // true
```

However that does not work with `std::string` without a copy. You can avoid the copy by using a view instead:

```
using case_insensitive_string_view =
    std::basic_string_view<char, case_insensitive_traits>;

std::string str = "Fundamental";

case_insensitive_string_view(str.data(), str.size()).starts_with("fun"); // true
```